# db.savechanges() is not commiting in database and even not giving any error

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I'm working on window form applications and I'm trying to update my database using ADO.net entity data model. this is my code

```
 private void AddJobAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            JobTable job = new JobTable();

                JobDatabaseEntities db = new JobDatabaseEntities();

                job.Project_name = this.ProjectName_txt.Text;
                job.Job_Number = this.JobNumber_txt.Text;
                job.Job_Value = int.Parse(this.JobValue_txt.Text);
                job.Sales_Initials = this.SalesInitials_txt.Text;
                job.Stage = this.Stage_combo.Text;
                job.Creation_Date = DateTime.Parse(this.CreationDate_dte.Text);
                job.Email = this.Email_txt.Text;
                job.Notes = this.Notes_txt.Text;

                db.JobTables.Add(job);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Form1 home = new Form1();
                this.Visible = false;
                home.Visible = true;
        }
```

This code is running without any error but when I check the database there is not any row of data so whenever I close the project all of the data that I save is lost.

I've a datagridview on Form1(home) page that is bound with my table. I can see my added data in datagridview after adding it but It's not reflecting in DB.

**Please Note** : My table has a Primary key of name Id that is set to identity.

I've also tried using

```
db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

before

```
db.JobTables.Add(job);
```

and using async function as

```
private async void AddJobAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but It's still not updating database.

I can delete and update my data too from datagridview but It's not committing in Database.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving data to correct database?

Comment: @Fabio I've only one database with a single table.